# Emirates route map

Tags: routes, emirates

I'm trying to find Emirates route map, specifically all flights that do NOT start/arrive from Dubai. Something like this would work https://aviationgeeks.pk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Emirates-route-map-2015.jpg if it was current.

I couldn't find anything useful on Emirate's website. Flightconnections.com is awkward since you basically need to click on each possible city.

Comment: _"specifically all flights that do NOT start/arrive from Dubai."_ - this is a strange request, given Dubai is the hub for Emirates (the only one, afaik). Why are you searching for these flights?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the static map that every airlines publishes in their in-flight magazine! Emirates Airlines magazine is called Open Skies. They publish it online via a website called issuu.com. Here's the link to the November 2018 issue.

[Open Skies, November 2018](https://issuu.com/motivatepublishing/docs/os_112018_digital)

See pages 90-95.